# Second domain pointing to subfolder of first domain won't rewrite port in IIS 8 URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, dns, windows-server-2012, multiple-domains

To try and make this as short as possible, I have two domains at work.

The first domain is our main domain at www.site1.com (port 80), pointing to a regular set up of a site in IIS 8, Server 2012.

The second domain is at www.site2.com (port 8085), but using some clever URL rewrite wizardry that I found on SO, www.site2.com points to www.site1.com/site2/, but behaves as if it were it's own domain. We did this in order to share assets between site1 and site2 in a .NET environment.

I do not have DNS-level control, but have admin of the server and it's settings and have done all of the URL rewriting for both sites myself. We received a request to install an SSL cert on www.site2.com (port 444) so that we can set the site to HTTPS. This is not relevant to the problem in itself because the problem exists in HTTP already.

The problem came about because another developer wants to be able to test the cert and the port configurations. As of right now, this isn't possible even in HTTP. Typing in www.site1.com:80 on the server works fine, but www.site2.com:8085 does not. site2 only connects properly when appended with www.site2.com:80 or just by typing in www.site2.com, I believe since it is rewritten as a subfolder off of site1.

I have tried everything I could think of in order to try and rewrite the ports in the URL so that the developer is able to test the port configuration by typing in www.site2.com:8085. The URL never resolves.

The bindings are set correctly as well because www.site2.com works fine in both test and production and has for years. It only does not work when the correct port is added to the URL.

This is the only code triggering the rewrite as it stands:

```
<rule name="www.site2 redirect" enabled="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?site2.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/site2/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in this way, just add one more condition into your rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="www.site2 redirect" enabled="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?site2.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?site2.com:8085$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/site2/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Another way to to that with one condition is (remove `$` from pattern in condiiton):

```
<rule name="www.site2 redirect" enabled="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?site2.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/site2/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

But this rule will capture domains like that as well: *site2.com.au, site2.com.fr, site2.com:{ANYPORT} etc.* That's why i prefer first rule

Comment: I tried both examples. Neither one allows the site to resolve when the port is added. The site still works without the port when these new rules are applied though.

Comment: I can't believe. I tested it twice and both time it's working. Did you restart website after your configuration changes?

Comment: No luck. I used your first example exactly and put the rewrite rule to the top of the list. I then restarted the website and web server. Did you add anything to the site bindings that I might be missing?

Comment: Do you have one app with this bindings? www.site2.com:8085, www.site2.com:80, www.site1.com ? Or it is different apps in IIS?